# Why won't my bullets shoot?

Tags: unity, 2d, shooter, shoot-em-up, top-down

I am making a top-down shooter in Unity (following a Brackeys tutorial for the top-down shooting mechanic). When I press the left mouse button a bullet prefab spawns, as it should, however there is no force applied to the bullet. As you will be able to see in the code, I have applied force to the bullet, I am not sure why it won't work. Any ideas guys? Thank you in advance!

This is my shooting script:

```
#region Variables
// floats
private float bulletForce = 130f;

// bools

// rigidbodies
private Rigidbody2D rb = null;

// transforms
public Transform firePoint = null;

// game objects
public GameObject bulletPrefab = null;
private GameObject bullet = null;
#endregion
#region Awake
// called before the script is initialised
private void Awake()
{

}
#endregion
#region Update
// called ever frame - used for checking for input
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
        Shoot();
    }
}
#endregion
#region FixedUpdate
// called at a fixed time - every 0.2 seconds - used for physics
private void FixedUpdate()
{

}
#endregion
#region Method - Shoot
// method to spawn bullet prefab and shoot bullet
private void Shoot()
{
    // spawn the bullet prefab at the position of fire point and rotate the prefab bullet to match the rotation of the player - name this newly created bullet by storing it in variable named bullet
    bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
    // store rigidbody on bullet game object in rb variable
    rb = bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    // add force to the bullet - impulse makes the bullet fly straight away - also in this line of code i get the angle offset variable from the player controller script
    rb.AddForce((firePoint.forward * gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerController>().angleOffset) *  bulletForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}
#endregion
```

}

This is my PlayerController script:

```
#region Variables
// floats
private float moveSpeed = 10f;
private float angle = 0f;
public float angleOffset = 270f;

// bools

// rigidbodies
private Rigidbody2D rb = null;

// vector2s
private Vector2 movement = Vector2.zero;
private Vector2 mousePos = Vector2.zero;
private Vector2 lookDirection = Vector2.zero;

// cameras
public Camera cam = null;
#endregion
#region Awake
// called before the script is initialised
private void Awake()
{
    // store rigidbody component in rb variable
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}
#endregion
#region Update
// called ever frame - used for checking for input
private void Update()
{
    // listen for horizontal input from the player - a and d or left arrow key and right arrow key
    movement.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    // listen for vertical input from the player - w and s or up arrow key and down arrow key
    movement.y = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    // find the mouse position, then convert the pixel position to world point and store that in a variable
    mousePos = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
}
#endregion
#region FixedUpdate
// called at a fixed time - every 0.2 seconds - used for physics
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    // move the player to the desired position - fixed delta time happens every time fixed update is called
    rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

    // find the direction the player needs to look by subtracting two vectors from each other
    lookDirection = mousePos - rb.position;
    // this finds the angle needed to calculate where the player should look then converts it to degrees
    angle = Mathf.Atan2(lookDirection.y, lookDirection.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - angleOffset;
    // rotate the player using the above maths
    rb.rotation = angle;
}
#endregion
```

}

[image]
The bullet just spawns Infront of the sprite and doesn't move.

[image]

Comment: Can you write a "Console.WriteLine" statement inside the method Shoot(), FixedUpdate(), and Update() to see if these methods are called ?

Comment: Thanks for getting in touch, I used a Debug.Log statement and yes, the method is called.

Comment: According to [Newton's_laws_of_motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion), When the force is applied for a very short time(one frame), it has little effect on the object's speed. So my first attempt would be to set the velocity directly on the bullet instead of applying force.

Comment: @Mangata note that they're using `ForceMode2D.Impulse` which accomplishes an instantaneous change in momentum, similar to setting velocity. I agree setting velocity directly is simpler, but the current method is not dependent on the time interval of the physics tick.

Answer (score 2):

It should have been .up instead of forward, because forward is for 3D. Then `*-1` because I want it to go in the opposite direction.